# Itertools object vanishes after the python script runs

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a python script, in which I do the following at one point:

```
iterator = product(*izip(repeat(0,len(myList)),myList))
```

I use the python command line, and do `execfile('myScript.py')`. After the code has run, I try the following:

```
>>> iterator
<itertools.product object at 0x182f06370>
>>> list(iterator)
[]
```

However, if I place a print statement in the script `print list(iterator)` right after `iterator` has been generated, the code prints the elements of the list correctly.

Why do the elements disappear after the file execution is done? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: It is an iterator. Once you have exhausted its contents, it will contain no elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator):

> Iterator is an object representing a stream of data. Repeated calls to the
>   iterator’s next() method return successive items in the stream. When
>   no more data are available a StopIteration exception is raised
>   instead. At this point, the iterator object is exhausted and any
>   further calls to its next() method just raise StopIteration again.